# Python - Websocket recv timeout - asyncio?

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio

So I'm doing some stuff with the websocket module and I want to add a timeout to the `recv` method. I'm familiar with a messy way of doing this with threading but I'm hoping to avoid that mess.

When I was looking this up, I saw some indication I should use `asyncio.wait_for`. I've never used asyncio so below is my first attempt at it. Also my first home-made context manager (which is fun)

```py
import websocket
import ssl
import json
import time
import asyncio

class WebsocketSession:
    def __init__(self, username, password, environment, id):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.env = environment
        self.id = id
    
    def build_login_credentials(self):
        return {
            # Redacted - login JSON
        }
    
    def url(self):
        # Redacted - returns the URL as a string
        
    def send(self, msg):
        self.ws.send(json.dumps(msg))

    async def find(self, selection_func, timeout=10):
        start_time = time.time()
        while True:
            elapsed = time.time() - start_time
            time_remaining = timeout - elapsed

            resp_str = await asyncio.wait_for(self.ws.recv(), timeout=time_remaining)
            resp = json.loads(resp_str)

            if selection_func(resp):
                print(f"Received Response: {resp}")
                return resp
            else:
                print(f"Received Type: {resp['type']}")
    
    def __enter__(self):
        self.ws = websocket.create_connection(
            self.url(),
            sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE}
        )
        self.ws.send(json.dumps(self.build_login_credentials()))

        login_resp = json.loads(self.ws.recv())
        # Redacted - login response error checking

        return self
    
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.ws.close()

async def main():
    username = "redacted"
    password = "redacted"
    env = "int"
    id = 123456

    with WebsocketSession(username, password, env, id) as ws_session:
        config = await ws_session.find(lambda resp: resp["type"] == "configList")
        # Stuff using config

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

When I run this, I get `TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required` on the `wait_for` call.

Firstly, if `wait_for` isn't actually the best way to do this, I'd love to hear a better solution. Either way, I am curious to know what I'm doing wrong. I'm struggling to find any clear information online other than `async def` but I can't `async def` the `recv` method myself